# Django How to iterate over list returned from ldap to save new object

Tags: python, django, ldap

I have the following model:

```
class SystemUsers(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    displayName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phoneNumber = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=10)
    emailAddress = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    employeeNumber = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have an ldap query that is returning the following from active directory:

```
user_details = []
            for entry in results:
                user_details.append(entry[1]['sAMAccountName'][0].lower())
                user_details.append(entry[1]['displayName'][0].replace(",", " "))
                user_details.append(entry[1]['telephoneNumber'][0].replace("-", ""))
                user_details.append(entry[1]['mail'][0].lower())
                user_details.append(entry[1]['employeeID'][0].lower())
                user_details.append(entry[1]['givenName'][0])
                user_details.append(entry[1]['sn'][0])

                return user_details
```

I am getting results as expected but I can't parse out the list to put it into a SystemUser(....).save() block to save it to the database. All I get is a list I can't loop over or set variables for.

When I do a

```
for item in user_details:
     print(item)
```

All I have are 7 lines of values. I can't get it so that item[0] is username, item[1] is displayname, etc, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the dict with the user data and use the `kwargs` magic:

```
field_names = ('username', 'displayName', 'phoneNumber', 'emailAddress',
               'employeeNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName', )
data = dict(zip(field_names, user_details)
SystemUser.objects.create(**data)
```

BTW may be it is a better idea to get the `user_details` as a dictionary from the beginning?

```
user_details = {
    'username': entry[1]['sAMAccountName'][0].lower(),
    'displayName': entry[1]['displayName'][0].replace(",", " "),
    'phoneNumber': entry[1]['telephoneNumber'][0].replace("-", ""),
    'emailAddress': entry[1]['mail'][0].lower(),
    'employeeNumber': entry[1]['employeeID'][0].lower(),
    'firstName': entry[1]['givenName'][0],
    'lastName': entry[1]['sn'][0],
}
SystemUser.objects.create(**user_details)
```

Comment: I've tried to get it as a dictionary, but basically the same thing happens. The list of items appears as a value in the dictionary but they all appear as one value of the dictionary. I tried your suggestion and I get a different error, "zip argument #2 must support iteration". I just can't seem to figure out how to make user_details iterable.

Comment: `useer_details` is a list so it is iterable. You iterate it in your question using the `for item in user_details` statement.

Comment: Yes. Your example of turning it into a dict from the start was the way to go. I don't know why I didn't see that an hour ago. Thanks so very much for your help.